# Human fingernail segmanation without training a model

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to mask human fingernails (fingernails white and everything including the hand is black). I do simple image operations then Canny edge detection after I smoothen the image then find contours to give internal contours white color which would be fingernails.

My problem is that when fingernails are painted it is quite easy to detect however when there is no paint it becomes really complicated and the program has to get 50 images and save outputs to a certain folder.

I am confused about how to proceed, if anybody did something similar I would appreciate some help.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def display_img(img):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,10))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')

img = cv2.imread('nail2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blur = cv2.blur(gray,ksize=(1,1))
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
display_img(blur)

med = np.median(gray)

gradient = cv2.Laplacian(blur,cv2.CV_64F)
gradient = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gradient)
plt.imshow(gradient,'gray')
lower = int(max(0,0.7*med))
upper = int(min(255,1.3*med))

edges = cv2.Canny(blur,lower,upper)

display_img(edges)

edges = cv2.GaussianBlur(edges, (11, 11), 0)  # smoothing before applying  threshold
display_img(edges)

image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Create empty array to hold internal contours
image_internal = np.zeros(image.shape)

# Iterate through list of contour arrays
for i in range(len(contours)):
    # If third column value is NOT equal to -1 than its internal
    if hierarchy[0][i][3] != -1:
        
        # Draw the Contour
        cv2.drawContours(image_internal, contours, i, 255, -1)

display_img(image_internal)
```

below is a good result:

[image]
[image]

some bad result even though fingers have pink paint:

[image]
[image]

Comment: always post unfiltered original pictures so people can analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have a big light and scale problem in these two images. But a possible solution is to segment the color channels and look for blobs.

[image: Merge and re-scale images.]

Then you can segment with blob params.

[image: Main fingers detected with blob detection.]

The code you can try here:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

fra = cv2.imread('nails.png')
height, width, channels = fra.shape

src = cv2.medianBlur(fra, 21)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV_FULL)

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, np.array([0, 0, 131]), np.array([62, 105, 255]))
mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=8)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=8)

params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = int((height * width) / 500)
params.maxArea = int((height * width) / 10)

params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.5
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.5
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
key_points = detector.detect(255 - mask)

vis = cv2.bitwise_and(hsv, hsv, mask=mask)
vis = cv2.addWeighted(src, 0.2, vis, 0.8, 0)
cv2.drawKeypoints(vis, key_points, vis, (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
for kp in key_points:
    cv2.drawMarker(vis, (int(kp.pt[0]), int(kp.pt[1])), color=(0, 255, 0), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS, thickness=3)

cv2.imshow("VIS", vis)
cv2.imwrite('nails_detected.png', vis)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Good luck!